# php or javascript regex - return the first letter and the remaining string as 2 separate values

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a code in php/mysql that gets ids from the database. The ids are in the form of a letter + a set of 3 digits. For example `a123`

I would like to be able to split the code to 2 variables `$var1 = 'a'` and `$var2 = '123'`

I thought of using php and regular expressions; looked at `preg_match`. I am not sure on how to get the first letter. I also thought about using `explode` in php and a limit or `str_split` like this:

```
$arr = str_split($str, 1);
```

but then this will split it into: a 1 2 3 4 and I'll end up with 4 values instead of 2. 
Any suggestions please. (I am open to doing it in javascript as well I can pass it through ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always 4 characters:

```
$var1 = substr($str, 0, 1);
$var2 = substr($str, 1, 3);
```

If you really want a regex:

```
([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{3})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regexps is really not necessary in this case.

`$letter = $id[0];`

$number = substr($id, 1);

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript it's easy (no regex needed):

```
var str = 'a123';​​
var stra = str.substring(0,1); // returns 'a'
var strb = str.substr(1); // returns '123'
```